# Simulated robot is building a tower of blocks in Gazebo 7, blocks are sliding

Tags: friction, gazebo-7

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I'm trying to have a Sawyer robot build a tower out of blocks but the blocks keep sliding off each other. I'm using Gazebo version 7. I've tried increasing the friction but it made no difference.

SDF file for blocks:

```
<robot name="block">
  <link name="block">
    <inertial>
      <origin xyz="0.025 0.025 0.025" />
      <mass value="0.5" />
      <!-- (1/12)*mass*(h^2 + d^2)  (1/12)*mass*(w^2 + d^2) (1/12)*mass*(w^2 + h^2) -->
      <!-- (1/12)*0.5*(0.045^2 + 0.045^2)  (1/12)*0.5*(0.045^2 + 0.045^2) (1/12)*0.5*(0.045^2 + 0.045^2) -->
      <inertia  ixx="0.00016874999" ixy="0.0"  ixz="0.0"  iyy="0.00016874999"  iyz="0.0"  izz="0.00016874999" />

    </inertial>
    <visual>
      <origin xyz="0.025 0.025 0.025"/>
      <geometry>
        <box size="0.045 0.045 0.045" />
      </geometry>
    </visual>
    <collision>
      <origin xyz="0.025 0.025 0.025"/>
      <geometry>
        <box size="0.045 0.045 0.045" />
      </geometry>
      <surface>
        <friction>
          <ode>
            <mu>9999999999.0</mu>
            <mu2>9999999999.0</mu2>
            <slip1>0.0</slip1>
            <slip2>0.0</slip2>
          </ode>
        </friction>
      </surface>
    </collision>
  </link>
  <gazebo reference="block">
    <material>Gazebo/Blue</material>
     <mu1>1000</mu1>
     <mu2>1000</mu2>
  </gazebo>
</robot>
```

SDF file for the world:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<sdf version="1.6">
  <world name="default">
    <include>
      <uri>model://ground_plane</uri>
    </include>

    <include>
      <uri>model://sun</uri>
    </include>

    <physics type="ode">
      <real_time_update_rate>1000.0</real_time_update_rate>
    </physics>
    
    <gravity>
      0.0 0.0 -9.81
    </gravity>

    <gui fullscreen='0'>
      <camera name='user_camera'>
        <pose frame=''>2.69836 -0.874828 2.04939 0 0.399643 2.75619</pose>
        <view_controller>orbit</view_controller>
        <projection_type>perspective</projection_type>
      </camera>
    </gui>

  </world>
</sdf>
```

SDF file for the tabletop the blocks are placed on top of:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<sdf version="1.4">
  <model name="cafe_table">
    <static>true</static>
    <link name="link">
      <collision name="surface">
        <pose>0 0 0.755 0 0 0</pose>
        <geometry>
          <box>
            <size>0.913 0.913 0.04</size>
          </box>
        </geometry>
      </collision>

      <collision name="column">
        <pose>0 0 0.37 0 0 0</pose>
        <geometry>
          <box>
            <size>0.042 0.042 0.74</size>
          </box>
        </geometry>
      </collision>

      <collision name="base">
        <pose>0 0 0.02 0 0 0</pose>
        <geometry>
          <box>
            <size>0.56 0.56 0.04</size>
          </box>
        </geometry>
      </collision>

      <visual name="visual">
        <geometry>
          <mesh>
            <uri>model://cafe_table/meshes/cafe_table.dae</uri>
          </mesh>
        </geometry>
      </visual>
    </link>
  </model>
</sdf>
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/21573/simulated-robot-is-building-a-tower-of-blocks-in-gazebo-7,-blocks-are-sliding/) by [Fuzzmeister](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/7750/fuzzmeister/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 3 on 2018-12-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

[This model](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo_models/src/b1ca744fff96db5c8016fc5a9270c003041e47fa/wood_block_stack/model.sdf?at=haptix_game_demos&fileviewer=file-view-default#model.sdf-29) of a stack of wood blocks like jenga should give you a starting point for which parameters to use. Note especially the `<contact>` tags.

---

Originally posted by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) with karma: 7504 on 2018-12-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0